# VBA Error 438 when trying to get class object from collection

Tags: vba, scripting

I have a class in vba called MyClass

```
Option Explicit

Private msg As String

Public Property Get Message()
    Message = msg
End Property
Public Sub Init(ByVal str As String)
    msg = str
End Sub
```

I want to populate collection with objects of that class so to test

```
Dim items As Collection
Dim Item As MyClass

Set items = New Collection

Set Item = New MyClass
Item.Init "test"

items.Add Item

Item = items.Item(1)
```

I not really speacilist in scripting i just need to do simple things so i dont understand why is it, but when i run the block above i get error:

> Run time error 438 Object' doesn't support this property or method

I checked in the debugger and it happens when i do step over on this line:
`Item = items.Item(1)`

How do i properly insert class objects to collection and get them back so i can use them without this error?

Comment: Missing `Set` ?  `Set Item = items.Item(1)`   Object-type variables need `Set` when assigning a value.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks it works. Does it mean that it is creating object clone or is it same object originaly created? Like is it working by reference

Comment: `Item` is getting a reference to the object stored in the collection.  It doesn't make a copy of the object.

Answer (score 0):

To be valid, `Item` must be an object type consistent with the object being assigned to it.

The `Dim`, `Private`, `Public`, `ReDim`, and `Static` statements only declare a variable that refers to an object. No actual object is referred to until you use the `Set` statement to assign a specific object.

So, don't forget to use the `Set` statement in VBA when you assign an object reference in the code:

```
Dim items As Collection
Dim Item As MyClass

Set items = New Collection

Set Item = New MyClass
Item.Init "test"

items.Add Item

Set Item = items.Item(1)
```